# Making a CSS input act like a table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the fiddle of what I'm trying to achieve: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k854hsae/)

```
.editable-field {
    display: block;
    justify-content: inherit;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.editable-input {
    border: none;
    font-size: inherit;
    background: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    transition: 0.3s all linear;
    width:100%
    height:100%;
}
```

Even with 100% width and height, the input doesn't seem to stretch along the cell.

I have a table where the cells expand vertically if the text is long (which is what I want). The problem is, if I want to have editable cells (such as the third one down in the demo), the input is static and doesn't "grow" with the text. Is there a css-only way, or J-Query to fix this?

Comment: Research: textarea auto grow

Comment: input won;t break to new line, have to use textarea for that

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k854hsae/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solutions may works for you .

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Not Editable but very long and takes fffffffffffffff multiple lines</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Not Editable</td>
        </tr>
        <td contenteditable >            
               asdfad
        </td>
        <tr>
            <td>Not Editable</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I used **contenteditable**. This is  html5 feature .

Comment: Awesome. With table-layout:fixed; I get the result I wanted. Thank you!